# I'm having trouble proving this derivative using the fundamental theorem of calculus

Tags: calculus

Prove, working directly from the definition, that if $f(x) = 1/x$ , then
$f'(a) = - 1/a^2$, for $a$ is not equal to $0$.

I keep getting $1/a ^2$ but not the negative by using $1/2a(a+h)-1/2a(a)/h$

This is Spivak's Fourth Edition of Calculus by the way.

Comment: Check your calculation, ${ {1 \over a+h} -{ 1 \over a} \over h } = -{1 \over a (a+h)}$.

Comment: Discrepancy: Your title says "using the fundamental theorem of calculus" and your question text says "directly from the definition".

Answer (score 1):

The result follows immediately from some algebraic manipulations:

\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x - a} & = \lim_{x\to a}\left(\frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{a}\right)\left(\frac{1}{x - a}\right)\\\\
& = \lim_{x\to a}\frac{a - x}{ax(x - a)}\\\\
& = \lim_{x\to a}-\frac{1}{ax} = -\frac{1}{a^{2}} 
\end{align*}

Hopefully this helps!